# Sudden error on MySQL IIS hosted website

Tags: mysql, iis, server, web, hosting

I have a VPS with Windows 2008 R2 with IIS web server, MySQL database server. I have hosted around 100 of websites on this server. One of the hosted website is throwing following error message:

" mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'MYSERVER' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' in C:\Domains\mydomain.com\wwwroot\include\config.php on line 21
Could not be connect to mysql"

This website hosted around 3 years ago. I have not made any changes in the code. But, all of a sudden, website has started throwing error message. After that, I have searched error logs and found following details:

ERROR: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MYSERVER@123'') WHERE User=''root''' at line 1

I have restarted service as well as rebooted server. But, it has not resolved MySQL error.

Comment: It looks to me from your error message like you recently added a new PHP application and/or a new MySQL database containing a table named `MYSERVER@123`.  That's an odd name for a table. It seems likely there are other flaws in this new application or database.

Comment: @OllieJones perhaps it was under attack? In either case, to me, the connect error vs. the 1064 are separate issues

Comment: I have monitored server as well as by our hosting provider. Reported NO attack on the server. We have added few websites on server but it should not conflict with already hosted websites as we have not made any changes in MySQL, PHP configuration.

We have repaired database too. But, no luck. Still checking further to resolve..

Comment: I have replaced localhost with MySQL server IP Address and allowed remote MySQL which has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to re-produce this error on my test server. You should check following:

→ You will have to make sure that the user you have added in your connection string is able to login to mysql server with the password you have entered in connection string. So, make sure that the username and password is correct.

→ Make sure that you have entered correct servername for mysql. If you are using local mysql (installed in same server), you should use 'localhost' in connection string. If you are using remote mysql server, make sure that you have entered it in connection string properly and that user must have remote access.